# How to store Google Sheets API response to file

Tags: file, go, multidimensional-array, google-sheets-api

In my quest to learn I want to store the response of a GSheet data range to a file for further use in another program.

From what I see GSheet API respond with a multidimensional array with cells data, so my first thought is to just use a for loop to write every row to a text file and reverse the process to append every row to a new array when reading it.

resp.Values is of type [][]interface{}
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#ValueRange

```golang
fmt.Println("Writing response to file:")
f, _ := os.Create("gSheetDump")
defer f.Close()

for _, row := range resp.Values {
    for _, column := range row{
        f.WriteString(column.(string)) //the cell data
        f.WriteString(" ") //space as column delimiter
    }
    f.WriteString("\n") //new row of data
}
f.Sync()
```

Error checks and other best practices omitted for simplicity.

In fact the code work in simple scenarios and I get a file with (just 2 column with random numbers for testing purpose)

```
0.1334477383 0.9119418
0.9302617807 0.6528034118
0.2401513927 0.7896743972
0.7807423779 0.006702754729
0.5697572871 0.4395454573
0.01565383694 0.1403231739
0.3567884312 0.6965423498
```

But problems arise when you get more complex data where a simple space isn't enough to separate columns.

There are some idiomatic way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json encoding instead of text:

```
json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(resp.Values)
```

This will write data into the file `f` as a JSON array. You cannot read it back using an [][]interface{}, you have to provide the concrete type:

```
var data [][]float64
json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&data)
```